# Adding items to tableview with sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I display a shopping list for different product groups as a table view with multiple sections. I want to add items with an add button for each group. So I equipped the header cell with a `UIToolbar` and a + symbol as a `UIBarButtonItem`.

[image]

Now every product group has an add button of his own:
[image]

If one add button was pressed, I have a problem identifying which one was pressed.

1. If I connect the add button with a seque, the function `prepareForSeque(...)` delivers a sender of type `UIBarButtomItem`, but there is no connection to the header cell from were the event was triggered.
2. If I connect an `IBAction` to the `UITableViewController`, the received sender is also of type `UIBarButtomItem`, and there is no connection to the header cell, too.
3. If I connect an `IBAction` to my `CustomHeaderCell:UITableViewCell` class, I am able to identify the right header cell.

This line of code returns the header cell title:

```
if let produktTyp = (sender.target! as! CustomHeaderCell).headerLabel.text
```

However, now the `CustomHeaderCell` class has the information I need.
But this information should be available in the `UITableViewController`.

I couldn't find a way to feed the information back to the `UITableViewController`.

```
    import UIKit

class CustomHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var headerLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func neuesProdukt(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let produktTyp = (sender.target! as! CustomHeaderCell).headerLabel.text
        {
            print(produktTyp)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add tag to barbuttonitem as item id or some unique data. and then neuesProdukt function you will get sender.tag as the unique id of the session.

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose There is only a single barbuttonitem with a single tag in the storyboard. In the tableview there are multiple barbuttonitems, one for each section. If any of them is pressed, the same sender.tag is returned.

Comment: yes . section names how you populating ? is it dynamic or  fixed?.

Comment: in sender.tag prefill the section index in the cellforrowatindex method. When the action is called validate the sender.tag and you will know which button section's button was clicked.

Comment: viewForHeaderInSection you can set the bar button tag as section. so it will get it in the target function.

Comment: @SubinKKuriakose Thanks a lot, your approach works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I typically handle this:

Use a Closure to capture the action of the item being pressed

```
class CustomHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var headerLabel: UILabel!

    var delegate: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?()
    }
}
```

When the Cell is created, create a closure that captures either the Index Path or the appropriate Section.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let section = indexPath.section
    let cell = createCell(indexPath)

    cell.delegate = { [weak self] section in
        self?.presentAlertView(forSection: section)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, too. However, I prefer @SubinKKuriakose's solution.